# in 21.04 i cant seem to adjust the font on the title bar

Tags: fonts, 21.04

[image: example]

In 21.04 I can not seem to adjust the font size of the title bar.

This effects other software such as google chrome, which is drawing it's font size choice for the URL bar, from the system title-bar font, so it is also not adjustable currently.

I am not sure if there is any way to adjust this, gnome tweaks or unity tweaks would be my go to, gnome tweaks didn't work as you can see from the image, and unity tweaks will not load at all.

Any assistance would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

To enlarge the font of your black top bar and google URL field:

- First reduce the fonts in "Tweaks", "Fonts" tab to a lower size that matches better the size of the font in the black top bar (e.g. set font sizes to 10 or 11)
- Then enlarge overall fonts by increasing the scaling factor, until font sizes are again to your liking. That will increase overall font sizes on the display.

Comment: using scaling produces weird overlapping fonts in chrome, i don't like this solution. it doesn't specifically address the problem i'd like to solve and is more of a work around.

Comment: Other solutions require hacking in css for the black top bar, and for chrome it will be a different fix. You now enlarged selected fonts. So other fonts remain small in comparison. I work with fonts of 11 pt and a scaling factor of 1.1 (currently) or 1.2 on a 1920x1080 display. I guess you have the same resolution, but better add it to your question (use "edit")

Comment: where are the css files for this. i think there should likely be an editor, but changing a number on a css file seems reasonable.